# python for loop printing list character instead of element

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries of which when i want to print the list index element of a key in the dictionary, the output is the index of the character and not the element.

```
reader = csv.DictReader(mycsvfile, fieldnames)
        for row in reader:
            print row
```

example output:

```
{'name':'tom','numbers':"['1','2','3']"} #row
```

print row['numbers']

```
['1',2','3'] #correct
```

print row['numbers'][0]

```
[           #wrong
```

How do i convert row['numbers'] to a list?

Comment: I think you missed a `'` before `2` in the line: `{'name':'tom','numbers':['1',2','3']} #row`. right?

Comment: @EbraHim yep, you are right. That is the cause.

Comment: sorry please see my edit. the list was actually a string.

Answer (score 0):

That's okay:

```
>>> row = {'name':'tom','numbers':['1','2','3']}
>>> row['numbers']
['1', '2', '3']
>>> row['numbers'][0]
'1'
>>> row['numbers'][1]
'2'
>>> row['numbers'][2]
'3'
>>>
```

Comment: please see my edit, the list was actually the string.